# What does $on.constructor do in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frameworks, xss

I was performing an XSS challenge on PortSwigger labs [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/dom-based/lab-angularjs-expression).

This is the solution to their XSS challenge

```
{{$on.constructor('alert(1)')()}}
```

However, with no prior experience in AngularJS I am rather lost. I was told that code within double curly braces `{{ }}` can be execute JavaScript expressions from anywhere in the code, providing the `ng-app` attribute (also known as an AngularJS directive) is somewhere in the HTML document. I also recognise `alert(1)` from ordinary JavaScript that creates a popup.

My question is what does the `$on.constructor` part do?

Answer (score 1):

`$on` is event handler function in Angular JS. The `$` sign just represents it is a function. `$on.constructor` is constructor function when invoked with parameters executes it's argument passed as a string. Thus passed with argument it is `$on.constructor('alert(1)')` and to denote constructor is a function "()" is added to look like: `$on.constructor('alert(1)')()`. This is similar to the following snippet in javascript:

```
function (){
   alert(1);
}
```